# Django pagination without the whole queryset

Tags: django, optimization

In Django, I use the paginator like the following:

from django.core.paginator          import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

```
def myView(request):
    ...
    paginator = Paginator(Annonce.objects.filter(name="huhu"), 10)
    paginator._count = s.count()
    try:
        annonces = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        annonces = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        annonces = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

In the s.search() function I do a query on my postgres db.

It turns out that even if I display 10 items per page, the query is not limited.

I tried to limit the query with a `Annonce.objects.filter(name="huhu")[:10]` and specifying the count myself. But the paginator doesn't work if I do  so.

Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: What are you putting in your context? And what are you iterating over?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view as your guide to writing a view function which uses django Paginator appropriately.

Notice that in the example code snippert -

```
def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')  # <--- This is the key to your solution.
```

`contact_list` is an assigned queryset which has not actually been evaluated yet.  The `paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25)` assignment to a `Paginator instance` is lazy and doesn't really get executed until it has to.

`page = request.GET.get('page')` gets your extra GET variable `?page=2` (as an example) from your url.  The url would actually look something like `http://localhost:8000/my/listing?page=2` when we attempt to retrieve the 25 objects that should appear on your listing page, page 2.

This is where the actual query to your database gets executed:-

```
try:
    contacts = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    contacts = paginator.page(1)
```

the `contacts = paginator.page(page)` executes a query to the database **retrieving only a limited set of objects based on the page number given to it** and on the condition that we want "25" objects per page.

Comment: Actually you're right. My design directly follows the one you describe. The only difference that made me think the result was evaluated when constructing the paginator is that I use a caching system for results. This was forcing the evaluation when constructing the paginator.

Comment: This example does not solve the problem and  will still invoke COUNT() query. Calling [Paginator.page(n)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/core/paginator/#Paginator.page) will call `Paginator.validate_number()` which will call `Paginator.num_pages()` which will call `count()` which will still invoke total COUNT() on database.